# How to manually set adress of Pointer in Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, pointers, delphi-xe7

I want to manually set address of Pointer to value stored in string variable. I have:

```
addr : String;
ptr  : Pointer;
```

then:

```
addr:='005F5770';
```

How to assign it to the `ptr`?

Comment: I admit I'm rather curious as to why you could possibly need to do this.  How does an address of valid memory in your private address space end up encoded in hex and stored in a string to begin with?

Comment: You can get the address, not sure if you can set the address of a pointer variable. What you can set is the pointer value, not the address.

Comment: @J... Usually after using a hacking tool to find addresses of life count variable in a game

Comment: @David: I admit I have never tried nor needed that, but wouldn't a hacker patch the executable(s), and not the running game?

Comment: @rudy often the games contain defence against that so patching at runtime can circumvent it

Comment: @David: Ok, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this:

```
ptr := Pointer($005F5770);
```

You don't need a string variable since the address is a literal that is known at compile time.

In fact you can make this a constant since the value is known at compile time:

```
const
  ptr = Pointer($005F5770);
```

Of course, if the value isn't a literal and really does start life as a string with hexadecimal representation then you first need to convert to an integer:

```
ptr := Pointer(StrToUInt64('$' + S));
```

Convert it to a `UInt64` so that your code is immune to 32 bit pointer truncation when compiled for 64 bit.

Answer (score 3):

Prepend the string hexadecimal number with `$` or `0x`and use the standard [StrToInt()](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.StrToInt):

```
ptr := Pointer(StrToInt('$'+addr));
```

If your pointer values are large and targeting a 64 bit compiler, consider using [StrToInt64()](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.StrToInt64)

---

Note that a typecast from integer to a pointer is needed.

Comment: I get `[dcc32 Error] Unit2.pas(33): E2010 Incompatible types: 'Pointer' and 'Integer'`